# PHP regex - Get hostname from a line of a textblock

Tags: php, regex, grep

I have a variable in PHP which holds a large text (an E-mail header to be precise).

I want to get 2 things out of this header. Here is a sample header:

```
Received: by mozg.ha.domain.net (Postfix, from userid 0)
    id E714C9AEDE; Tue, 29 Mar 2011 10:22:42 +0200 (CEST)
Subject: This is some text before hs34940.somedomain.tld
X-internal-Template: mozg/de/shipping.model
```

Now, from this text, I want to get 2 variables.
One containing *hs34940.somedomain.tld* and the other one the 4 last digits of the number, in this case *4940*. The length of the digits is variable.

I have got this currently in the variable $header, and I'd love to get $number and $name out of it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: is `somedomain.tld` going to remain constant or will vary ?

Comment: somedomain.tld can be 2 different values. It can be or some1.tld or domain2.tld.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well here is a simple approach, use regular expressions one to get this line:

```
Subject: This is some text before hs34940.somedomain.tld
```

Another inside the first match to get : hs34940.somedomain.tld

And for the number just use a substr if the number of digits is fix.

Useful API:

[Preg_match($pattern,$match,$result)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) - to match patterns against text.

[substr($start_indes,$finish_index,$string)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) - to get a specific part of a string.

---

For the Subject headline: `preg_match('/Subject: [a-zA-Z0-9.  ]*/', $header, $headline);`
For the domain: `preg_match('/[a-z0-9]*[.][a-z0-9]*[.][a-z]*/', $headline[0],$domain);`

This isn't too general tho, but for your case will work just fine.

Comment: That's what I've been trying to do, but I can't seem to figure out how to get any valid content into it :/

Comment: What seems to be the problem? Regular expressions are not matched?

Comment: I guess so ... It returns a "Valid Array" but that's empty. Could you add an example above on how to get hs34940.somedomain.tld ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert at regex but this might help.

```
preg_match('/\d{4}\.somedomain.tld.*|\.somedomain1.tld.*/', $header, $arr);
```

$arr[0] will give you `4940.somedomain.tld`

I tried with [this tool](http://www.spaweditor.com/scripts/regex/index.php)

Then you may use substr or explode to get the number and the domain name